# Як правильніше вживати, "в" чи "до"?

Tags: вживання-слів, прийменники

Як правильно сказати: *"піти до банку"* чи *"піти в банк"*? Яке граматичне правило для цього застосовується?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Зацитую [«Як ми говоримо» Бориса Антоненка-Давидовича](http://yak-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/pryjmennyky):

> Інколи виникає питання, який прийменник треба ставити – у (в) чи до: "Я поїхав у Київ" чи "Я поїхав до Києва", "Вихід у місто" чи "Вихід до міста"?
>
> Узагалі, коли мовиться про рух у напрямі міста, села, селища, тоді треба ставити прийменник до: «Через кілька днів Ковпак вилетів до Москви» (П. Вершигора); коли йдеться про дію чи перебування в чомусь, тоді слід користуватися прийменником у (в): «У Києві на риночку ой пив чумак горілочку» (народна пісня). Якщо мета руху в певному напрямі супроводжується ще додатковими поясненнями, тоді після них може стояти замість прийменника до — у (в): «Ми їздили на ярмарок у Косів» (М. Рильський). У реченнях, де рух або дію скеровано до предметів, середовищ або мовиться про абстрактні поняття, ставиться прийменник у (в): «Він ступив у сад» (Є. Гуцало); «Кидається у свою стихію» (О. Гончар); «Закрадається в серце острах» (М. Рильський). Рух до приміщення позначається дієсловами з тим і з другим прийменником: «Уваливсь у хату» (П. Куліш); «Смерть зайшла до хати» (Д. Павличко).

Прямої поради саме для цього випадку тут немає, лише деяки риси того, на чому взагалі може ґрунтуватися вибір. Обидва варіанти є правильними, розрізняючись лише деякими нюансами. Наприклад, чи мається на увазі перебування всередині? За моїм загальним уявленням виходить, що без уточнень, коли ми говоримо про похід до установи, звичніше використовувати «до». «У цирк», «у кіно» — це більш звично з «у».

Comment: Я не розумію з чого Ви зробили висновок, що краще «до банку». (1) «у напрямі міста, села, селища» — ні; (2) «дію чи перебування в чомусь» — ні (це взагалі про місцевий відмінок вже); (3) «супроводжується ще додатковими поясненнями» — ні; (4) «рух або дію скеровано до предметів, середовищ або мовиться про абстрактні поняття» — незрозуміло. Тобто мені особисто Б. А.–Д. тут не допоміг (хоча, може, я його просто не так читаю).

Comment: Ви маєте рацію. Він не дає прямої відповіді, як краще в даному випадку. Тому це я невірно підсумував.

Answer (score 24):

Як можна бачити в СУМ, [до](http://sum.in.ua/s/do) й [в/у](http://sum.in.ua/s/v) мають багато спільного, коли йдеться про просторові відношення. Проте є важливі відмінності:

1. Коли йдеться про пункт призначення, треба використовувати "до".
2. "В" має значення "всередину". Тобто "я прийшов до банку" може означати, що я підійшов до дверей банку чи що я зайшов усередину банку. "Я прийшов у банк" точно означає, що я вже всередині банку.

Таким чином, можна використовувати обидва варіанти, але вони матимуть дещо різне забарвлення. "до" використовувати безпечніше, наприклад:

"Я пішов до банку й дорогою зустрів однокласника": можна лише "до", бо тут "банк" - пункт призначення руху, в нього не заходили.

"Я пішов у банк і переказав гроші" - можна "у", бо ви заходили. Проте тут можна й "до".

Answer (score 14):

М. Вакуленко у своїй монографії «Українська термінологія: комплексний лінгвістичний аналіз» (що її сам автор [опублікував під вільною ліцензією](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%9C.%D0%9E._%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F-_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B7.pdf)) присвячує цій темі розділ 3.2.4 «Особливості вживання українських прийменників „в“ („у“) і „до“ для позначення мети та напрямку руху» (він також [викладений на форумі](http://r2u.org.ua/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=6864)).

### Загальна позиція М. Вакуленка

Наводячи численні вжитки прийменників (а також префіксів) «в» та «у» у фразеологізмах, сучасних виразах, поезії та прозі, В. Вакуленко робить висновок, що **сучасне вживання прийменника «до» в багатьох випадках є надмірним і штучним**:

> <sub>Така велика кількість уживань прийменника «в (у)» на позначення мети руху порівняно з відносно малою кількістю «до» свідчить про закономірність, яка усталилися в українській мові. У цьому довкіллі **нововиправлені вирази з прийменником «до» на місці «в (у)» сприймаються як чужі**: *взяти **до** рук*, *покласти **до** рота (кишені)*, *повернутися **до** Києва*, *прибути **до** аеропорту*, *приїxати **до** столиці* тощо. Ось кілька прикладів із сучасних засобів масової інформації: *делегація прибула **до** Страсбурга*; *президент повернувся **до** Києва*; *взяв книжку **до** рук*; *Єршов… поїхав навчатися **до** Петербурга в університет*; *поклав гроші **до** кишені*.</sub>

Він вважає **«до» антонімом до «від», а «в» («у») — до «з»**:

> <sub>Прийменник «до» означає «наближення» (або «додавання») до чого-небудь або до кого-небудь: *підійти **до** стола*, *приїхати в гості **до** друга*, *наближатися **до** міста*. Антонім цього прийменника — *від*: *відійти **від** стола*, *їхати **від** друга*, *віддалятися **від** міста*, ***від*** Києва до Лубен. Якщо ж ідеться про переміщення всередину (в межі) об’єкта, і увага акцентується саме на цій кінцевій меті руху, то вживається прийменник *в* (антонім — *з*): *увійти **в** кімнату* (*вийти **з** кімнати*), *покласти **в** шухляду* (*вийняти **з** шухляди*), *приїхати **в** Україну* (*поїxати **з** України*).</sub>

Він:

- **погоджується з позицією Ю. Шевельова** про дієслівні префікси (семантика яких тісно пов’язана зі значенням відповідних прийменників), що «*в* (*у*) має основним значенням показувати рух усередину предмета», а «*до* показує наближення до предмета».
- але **критикує частину формулювань Б. Антоненка-Давидовича**:

  > <sub>Різниця між цими прийменниками особлива відчутна у виразах, де семантика вимагає вживання як «в (у)», так і «до»: *приїхати **у** Львів **до** брата*, *поїхати **в** Петербург **до** університету*, *зайти **в** клітку **до** левів*.</sub>
  >
  > <sub><…></sub>
  >
  > <sub>У своїй книжці «Як ми говоримо» Борис Антоненко-Давидович також зупинявся на цьому питанні. І прийшов до подібних нашим висновків: «Узагалі, коли мовиться про рух у напрямі міста, села, селища, тоді треба ставити прийменник *до*…». Зауважмо: *рух у напрямі*, а не *прибуття*. І далі: «Якщо мета руху в певному напрямі супроводжується ще й додатковими поясненнями, то після них може стояти замість прийменника *до* — *у* (*в*)…» А це вже **не зовсім вдале формулювання**. «Мета руху» — на відміну від вирушання в невизначеному напрямі — однозначно вимагає вживання «у (в)», і не замість «до». А «додаткові пояснення» — то насправді обставини, що підкреслюють необхідність уживання «у (в)» (дуже часто ці обставини потребують для себе прийменника «до», як у виразі «поїхати у Львів до брата»). Саме такі висновки напрошуються після уважного вивчення наведених вище прикладів. І далі: «У реченнях, де рух або дію скеровано до предметів, середовищ або мовиться про абстрактні поняття, ставиться прийменник *у* (*в*)…».</sub>

  Тобто, на відміну від Б. Антоненка-Давидовича, за М. Вакуленко вважає, що вживання прийменника «в» («у») у фразі, наприклад, «приїхати *у* Львів до брата» обумовлене **не тим, що присутні додаткові пояснення з прийменником «до»** (тобто не тим, що «приїхати до Львова до брата» — просто немилозвучно/тавтологія), а тим, що сама перша частина **«приїхати *у* Львів» уже в будь-якому разі вимагає прийменника «в» («у»)**, а друга частина «до брата» лише робить наочною семантичну різницю, дадатково стимулюючи поставити правильний (на думку М. Вакуленка) прийменник «в» («у») у фразі «приїхати *у* Львів».

### Конкретні настанови М. Вакуленка

М. Вакуленко дає такі настанови щодо «в» («у») і «до»:

> - <…> в більшості випадків слід уживати прийменник «*в* (*у*)» — особливо якщо відповідне дієслово явно означає прибуття чи переміщення в пункт прямування: *приїхати **в** Америку*, *вставити **у** вухо*, *увійти **в** будинок*, *пробратися **в** кабінет*, *взяти **в** долоні*, *покласти **в** рот* (*кишеню*), *помістити **у** валізу*, *прибути **в** аеропорт*, *повернутися **в** Київ*, *внести **в** касу*, *покласти **в** банк* тощо.
> - Якщо ж дієслово означає просто рух у якомусь напрямку, то можливе вживання як «до», так і «в (у)»: *поїхати **до** Києва, податися **в** село **до** бабусі*.
> - Якщо ж мовиться тільки про наближення до певних осіб, предметів чи понять, то вживається «до»: *прошу **до** столу*, *завітайте **до** нас*, *заходьте **до** господи* (*хати*), *взяти **до** уваги* тощо.
>
> Окремо відзначимо вирази на зразок *ходити **до** школи*, *вступити **до** інституту*, *поїхати в Петербург (Київ, Москву) **до** університету* тощо. Найчастіше в таких виразах увага акцентується не на перебуванні в межах відповідного приміщення, а на залученні до процесу навчання: це опанування навчальної програми, спілкування з викладачами та друзями і т. п. — тому тут потрібен прийменник «до». Якщо ж ідеться саме про переміщення всередину будівлі навчального закладу, то потрібен «в (у)»: *зайти **в** школу*, *заскочити **в** інститут*.

Він так пояснює використання «до» в деяких виразах:

> Вислови на зразок *падати **до**долу*, *поїзд **до** Києва*, *подорож **до** Ялти* тощо позначають рух у певному напрямі, де акцент робиться саме на пересуванні, тобто зміні початкового місцеположення, а не на прибутті в кінцевий пункт призначення.
>
> *Прошу **до** господи*, *заходьте **до** хати* — означають, крім вищесказаного, ще й «прошу (завітати) до нас», тобто *до людей*. *Повертатися **до**дому* (тут прийменник став префіксом) означає «повертатися до батьків, рідних». *Прошу **до** столу* — означає, крім того, «прошу (ставати) до трапези» (якби мався на увазі предмет — було б *до стола*). *Брати **до** уваги* — означає *скеровувати інформацію в певне русло*. *Брати до рук* — означає *брати собі якесь доручення*. Тому *взяти до рук* можна завдання, але не книжку. *Складати **до**купи* — означає *складати речі ближче одна до іншої*. «Скидати *в* купу» — означає *скидати речі в одне місце*.

### Висновки

За теорією М. Вакуленка, яку, однак, не можна вважати повністю авторитетною і беззаперечною:

- В разі перебування в дорозі можна вживати і «в» («у»), і «до»: «я йду *в* банк», «я йду *до* банку». Перше, мабуть, акцентує увагу на меті/пункті призначення, а друге — на фактичному напрямку. «Я йду в центральний супермаркет, зараз рухаюся вулицею, що виходить до старого замку.»
- Якщо Ви вже всередині, то загалом слід вживати «в» («у»): «я прийшов *у* банк». Проте, мабуть, можна вжити «до», якщо Ви ще не всередині або якщо те, всередині Ви чи ні, немає для Вас значення:

  - «Я йшов на роботу, але випадково прийшов до банку.»
  - «Я багато років працював у банку „Ххх“ і мав дружні стосунки з багатьма колегами. Після виходу на пенсію я все ще часто приходжу до банку [до колег] випити кави зі старими друзями.»

Примітка: це не стосується слів на позначення установ, що сприймаються в першу чергу не як приміщення, а як частина системи, наприклад, «[пошта](http://sum.in.ua/s/poshta)» — в такому випадку буде відбуватися аналогічний вибір між «на» і «до» (а не між «в» («у») і «до»).

Answer (score 4):

## До

Словоформи з прийменником **до** творяться тільки з **родовим відмінком** іменників:

- мету руху, його просторову або часову межу: *до школи, до берега, до Києва, до серця, до ранку;*

## В

Словоформи з прийменником **в (у)** мають переважно просторове значення:

- із **знахідним відмінком** іменника найчастіше вказують на рух усередину: *у кімнату, у море, у поле, у світ*;

---

## [Себто](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/chinnij_pravopis/7-1-0-161)

- *Куди* пішов — рух — до

  > Бесїда телефоном між дівчатами, одна ся жаліла журбою ранїше.
  >   — А куди твій красень ся запропастив?
  >   — Та пішов до банку гроші забирати.
- *Результативна* дія — в

  > Дівчата ся веселять в торговому будинку в вихідний день. Одна дівчина ся повернула з примірки.
  >   — Га, а де твій красень ся запропастив? Хтїла, аби забавив мій вигляд красними словечками, хе!
  >   — Та *зайшов* в оцей банк і чогось не виходить.

Comment: Не зовсім зрозумів. Тобто во вважаєте, що якщо бачили, як зайшов всередину — то «в», а як не бачили (може, зайшов, а може, й до коханки подався) — то «до»? Чи як?

Comment: А чому в першому випадку результативність не всередині? (Я не «не погоджуюся», просто пояснено так, що до кінця не зрозуміло (мені принаймні).) Типу, в першому випадку важлива сама взаємодія з організацією «Такий-то банк» (і не важливо, всередині клієнт чи ні, теоретично може навіть прямо на вулиці взаємодія організована бути, як у [«МакДрайв»](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonald's#McDrive)), а в другому важливий сам факт знаходження всередині будівлі?

Comment: Мабуть, це слід детальніше пояснити у відповіді. Бо якщо я з двома додатковими запитаннями ще не до кінця зрозумів позицію, то сторонньому читачу може бути ще важче зрозуміти. (Але як — **не знаю**, бо я сам до кінця не зрозумів; як наступне контрзапитання, хотів поставити: «А якщо ринок не критий (базар), то в такому випадку „до ринку“≡„на ринок“?» — але боюся, що я все-таки не в тому напрямку подумав…)