# Вступати на магістратуру чи до магістратури

Tags: словосполучення, прийменники, керування-відмінками

В [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/vstupaty) надано такі варіанти керування дієслова вступати:

> ВСТУПАТИ 1 (УСТУПАТИ), аю, аєш, недок., ВСТУПИТИ (УСТУПИТИ), вступлю,
>   вступиш; мн. вступлять; док.
>
> 1. у що. Ставати, ступати в середину чого-небудь.
>
> //  Всувати ноги без панчіх, онуч у чоботи, черевики тощо.
>
> 2. до чого, у що, на що. Входити, в'їжджати куди-небудь.
>
> //  По дорозі заїжджати, заходити куди-небудь.
>
> ♦ Вступати (вступити) в [свої] права — проявлятися в усій своїй силі.
>
> 3. перен. Проникати в кого-, що-небудь.
> 4. **до чого, у що, на що.** Ставати членом якої-небудь організації, товариства і т. ін.    //  **Поступати до навчального закладу,
>      починати вчитися.** Микола.. теж вступає в університет, тільки не на
>      літературний, а на біологічний факультет (Григорій Тютюнник, Вир,
>      1964, 54); Павлусь вступив на бібліотечні курси (Олесь Донченко, II,
>      1956, 15);  //  Займати посаду. Разом з благочинним поїхав [Балабуха]
>      у Вільшаницю, щоб вступити на парафію (Нечуй-Левицький, III, 1956,
>      61).

На інтернет-ресурсах використовується прийменникове сполучення [вступати до магістратури](http://philology.knu.ua/node/273), [вступати у магістратуру](http://testportal.gov.ua/tag/vstup-u-magistraturu/) і [вступ на магістратуру](http://studway.com.ua/perekhresnijj-vstup-na-magistraturu/). Чи всі ці варіанти є синонімічними і правильними, чи лише один із них є нормативним?

Comment: Related: https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/271/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оскільки **магістратура** - абстрактне поняття, то, як філологи кажуть, семантика завуальована.

Річ у тім, що прийменники мають два різних значення - конкретне (просторове, первинне) і абстрактне (переносне, вторинне).

І переносне значення прийменника сильно залежить від контексту словосполучення з приєднуваним словом.

При цьому для **магістратури** маємо щонайменше два значення - **курс** і **організація** (відділ).

> **Магістратура** - один або декілька курсів навчання після отримання
>   диплома бакалавра або спеціаліста у вищих навчальних закладах, а також
>   відділ, що забезпечує підготовку магістра.

[е-словник](http://eslovnyk.com/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0)

Коли **магістратура** стане в контекст курсу (також абстрактного слова), варто приєднувати цю лексему до дієслова за допомогою прийменника **на**, за аналогією **ступати на шлях**, адже курс є тривалою в часі дією з кінцевою метою.

Якщо ж **магістратура** означає певний робочий відділ, куди я, скажімо, йду забрати певну річ - довідку, наприклад, то варто вживати прийменник **до**, аналогія - конкретний напрямок руху, наближення, як **іти до поліклініки**.

Якби теоретично можна було вступити до магістратури як до партії, тобто приєднатися до певного кола людей, то був би тут також прийменник **до**.

Comment: А в чому протирічча вступу до магістратури, як до партії, приєднуючись до певного кола людей? Це ж так і є!

Comment: @user6400, так, мені теж здається, що така аналогія принаймні не слабша за «вступати на шлях».