# "Додати в кошик" чи "Додати до кошика"

Tags: правопис

На сайті інтернет-магазину на кнопці правильніше написати "Додати в кошик" чи "Додати до кошика"?

Answer (score 4):

На основі [дубля](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/271/%D0%AF%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE)

пропоную використати "Покласти в кошик" або "Додати в кошик", бо мова йде про перенесення чогось всередину об'єкту.

Comment: А «додати до кошика» у мене особисто асоціюється з тим, що кошик — це один із куплених чи вибраних предметів. Типу, я вже купив чи вибрав олівець, кошик, джинси — і тепер до олівця, кошика, джинсів додаю ще фен. Тобто «додати до» найбільше пасує, коли ми додаємо предмет до ряду подібних; а оскільки кошик — це не куплений/вибраний предмет, а лише уявне вмістилище для куплених/вибраних предметів, то мені здається, «додати до» — не найкраще. Але можу помилятися.

Comment: "Додати до кошика", або "покласти в кошик". Не знаю, чому -- здається очевидним... Проте, згоден з @Sasha -- "додати до кошика" може бути невірно прочитано...